# Should i recalculate big amounts of data from tables, or should I save it in my database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-normalization

My question is more general than specific, yet I am using an example to transfer the idea.

I have a forum, and in each replay I present the number of messages the users have.

Assuming that in some pages there are 15 different users, each has over 20,000 messages, should I recalculate the number of messages by counting how many entries in the messages table the user has, or would it be better to create a column in the users table that contains this data, and update the column every time a reply is made?

I know it defies the database normalizations rules, but it seems like a big waste to calculate it every time.

I'm using mySQL, if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

Generally no, but in some specific cases, yes.

You should avoid having redundant data in a database. However, sometimes you have to make that tradeoff to get a decent performance.

I have actually done exactly the thing in your example. It works great for the performance, but it's really hard to keep the message count correct. You will get some inconsistent values sooner or later, so you need a plan for how to go through the values periodically and recalculate them.

Comment: You could have a daily cron job that recalculates them.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization). [Quoting wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization):

> denormalization is the process of attempting to optimise the read
>   performance of a database by adding redundant data or by grouping
>   data.

Keep denormalized data in 'plain' code is not an easy issue. Remember than:

- You can keep redundant data with **triggers**.
- If your architecture includes **[ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)** it is more easy to keep redundant data.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go half way in your denormalisation: have a table with monthly data per user, filled by a monthly job, and calculate the number of messages on the fly, by counting the msg since 1st of month + sum of monthly data. Or if you don't need the monthly data, you can still calc on the fly over the month + a monthly process that updates the EOM figues. That will avoid triggers...

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned materialized views.  These objects are very helpful when it comes to maintaining aggregates of data for performance reasons without violating the normalisation of our actual data.  [Find out more](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to benchmark the results of counting the number of rows?
I'd recommend you just do you're calculation in a view. With the denormalization you're proposing, you're just exposing yourself to the risk of data corruption. The post count column will then end up with some arbitrary value that's go nothing to do with the reality of the number of posts.